# What is the proper way to link to a background image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

In production, I have had no problem linking to assets outside of my css. But I can't seem to find the rails logic to apply the fingerprints to my images, and this is causing 404s on every background image file. Here is what I have tried:

```
background-image: url(image-path('pretty-background-image.jpg'));
background: asset-url('pretty-background-image.jpg');
```

but neither of those seem to work, they both set the path to:

```
background: url(assets/pretty-background-image.jpg);
```

instead of

```
background: url(assets/pretty-background-image1234567890987654321.jpg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to use sass and the `image-url` helper

```
background-image: image-url("path/to/file.jpg")
```

Given that your file is located in /app/assets/images/path/to/file.jpg

More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

---

**EDIT** As it's not working on your case, just do the following verification

In your dev machine, run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` from your app directory.

Then go in the *public* directory and search for your image file, and verify it is fingerprinted.

Still in your *public* directory, open the compiled css file and search for your CSS selector to verify that `image-url` was replaced by `url` and the file path is fingerprinted.

Tell me the result, we'll see

Comment: That still doesn't seem to be adding the fingerprint. Is that something I need to manually add to the filename?

Comment: It is working automatically. 1. is it working in dev environment? 2. are you compiling assets during deploy?

Comment: Also be sure that `config.assets.digest` is `true` in production

Comment: Yes, both on the production server, and running `rails server -e production` locally causes this to happen. I'm not sure about configuration.assets.digest (I'm not at my home computer), but all of the assets that aren't used in SCSS (e.g. image tags) are fingerprinted.

Comment: Awesome. I'll take a look at this after work. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, sorry - just now getting back to this. Yes, the file is in the public directory, and has a fingerprint.